# Executing original function from each decorator using multiple decorators in python

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-decorators, aiohttp

The following is a simplistic example of what I'm trying to do. The function 'print_number' below is wrapped by 2 decorators.

```
def another_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        ret = function(*arg, **kwargs)
        print(ret, "executed from another_decorator")
    return wrapper

def test_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        ret = function(*arg, **kwargs)
        print(ret, "executed from test_decorator")
    return wrapper

@another_decorator
@test_decorator
def print_number(num):
    return num
x = print_number(222)
print(x)
```

The above returns

```
222 executed from test_decorator
None executed from another_decorator
None
```

As you can see, only the test_decorator was able to execute the wrapped print_number function. The call to this function was entirely skipped in the another_decorator.
Some context on why I need this. I have some code where I'm wrapping a main async function with multiple decorators where I need to call the async function by each decorator. Each decorator does some preliminary work to pass to the called async function where a aiohttp session is created and a coroutine is scheduled using ensure_future.
Is there a way or possible procedure to call the wrapped function 'function', from each decorator?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

you need to actually return in your decorators .. .additionally functions are just objects in python so give your wrapper function an attribute "original"

```
def another_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        ret = function(*arg, **kwargs)
        print(ret, "executed from another_decorator")
        return ret
    wrapper.original = getattr(function,"original",function)
    return wrapper

def test_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        ret = function(*arg, **kwargs)
        print(ret, "executed from test_decorator")
        return ret
    wrapper.original = getattr(function,"original",function)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really interesting and this does work though it's hard for me to see what's happening here. I get it that in the getattr, you are gettting the default 'function' value since 'original' does not exist in the object 'function'. I hesitatingly concede that retrieval of the value 'executes' function and the 'print_number' function is called. But I don't really understand why this works. Previously,  I used functool.wraps and tried to execute function.__wrapped__() in 'another_decorator' and that did not work.